# Valgrind and strlen() function bug

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

i have some examination program. The examination system works with valgrind.

Please, help me
I have some bug in valgrind and i dont know, how solve it bug in my program:
I want to copy stdin to *in pointer and remove all spaces and newlines from stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELTA 2
unsigned int my_strlen(char *str);
char *get_expression(void);
int main(void)
{
    char *in, *out;
    in = get_expression();
    if (!in) {
        return 1;
    }
    out = calloc(my_strlen(in), 1);
    free(out);
    free(in);
    return 0;
}
char *get_expression(void)
{
    char *in, *in_bckp, t;
    in = malloc(DELTA);
    if (!in) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0, c = DELTA; (t = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
        if (i >= c) {
            in_bckp = in;
            in = realloc(in, c + DELTA);
            if (!in) {
                free(in_bckp);
                return NULL;
            }
            c += DELTA;
        }
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') { // i need to remove all of the spaces or newlines
            continue;
        }
        in[i] = t;
    }
    if (i >= c) {
        in_bckp = in;
        in = realloc(in, c + DELTA);
        if (!in) {
            free(in_bckp);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    in[i] = '\0';
    return in;
}

unsigned int my_strlen(char *str)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0' && i < 40000; i++);
    return i;
}
```

and my bug from valgrind:

```
ivr@debian:/tmp
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./a.out < ~/work/programming/kursovik/parsing/test/data
==5044== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5044== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5044== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5044== Command: ./a.out
==5044== 
==5044== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5044==    at 0x4007D5: my_strlen (test.c:59)
==5044==    by 0x400666: main (test.c:16)
==5044== 
==5044== 
==5044== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5044==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5044==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 17 frees, 280 bytes allocated
==5044== 
==5044== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5044== 
==5044== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5044== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

please help me solve this bug.

Comment: 1st of all compile with symbols (option `-g` for gcc) to enable Valgrind to precisely reference the sources. 2ndly run Valgring with the optiion `--track-origins=yes` to point you where the uninitialised value comes from.

Comment: Have you followed Valgrind's advice to re-run the job with `--track-origins=yes`? That should give you a good hint.

Comment: It however seems you are not taking care of the `0`-termination to make a `char`-array a valid C-"string", when allocating and initialising `in`.

Comment: `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')` -- Here, `c` is your allocation size. That should be `t`, which is the result from `getchar()`. Please chose meaningful names.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but valgrind detects an error

Answer (score 2):

You leave gaps in your `in` array. Basically, you say:

```
int i, t;

for (i = 0; (t = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
    if (t == ' ' || t == '\n') continue;
    in[i] = t;
}
```

When you read a space or a new-line character, you skip the assignment, but increment `i++`. Valgrind (correctly) recognises these gaps in `in` as unitilialised memory.

A `for` loop isn't a good choice here. A `while` loop might be better:

```
int t;
int i = 0;

while ((t = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (t != ' ' && t != '\n') in[i++] = t;
}
```

Note how the counter `i` is incremented only when an assignment occurs. These two events, which are closely related, are carried out nearly simultaneously.

Comment: I need to remove all of the spaces and new lines.

Comment: And the code I've shown doesn't do that? (The code is just the heart of the loop, without the dynamic allocation.)

Comment: change (c != ' ' && c != '\n') to (t != ' ' && t != '\n')

Comment: Okay, corrected. (I've copied your error from above, where I had admonished you for not using good variable names. Oh, well.)

Comment: yes, I figured t = temp, c = count, but the names relly bad

Comment: The names are not bad per se. If you use `t` (temp) and `c` (count) consistently, that's okay, but you seem to have confused yourself. I think a single-letter name for the character you read is okay, because you will use that often. I would have chosen a somewhat longer name for the count, maybe `count`. (But by no means `allocated_char_count` :-)